# Inserting graphics into asymptote or pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, graphics, asymptote

How another graphics can be inserted into Asymptote or pgfplots? The following is a MWE in pgfplots that creates three figures in the document. The main figure which I want to insert graphics in is a pgfplot graphics and the other two are a vector or a raster graphics.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
Figure 1 is the main figure that will be used for the insertion of a vector or a raster graphics.
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            colormap={bw}{gray(0cm)=(0); gray(1cm)=(1)}]
        \addplot+[scatter,only marks,
             domain=0:8,samples=100]
            {exp(x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{This is the main figure.}
\end{figure}

Figure 2 is a graphics which I want to be inside figure 1, which is a vector graphics. I want to place it in the upper left corner position.
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[colormap/bluered]
        \addplot+[scatter,
             scatter src=x,samples=50]
            {sin(deg(x))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{This figure needs to be inside figure 1.}
\end{figure}

Figure 3 is another graphics which I want to be placed inside figure 1 in the upper left corner.
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{piv.jpg}
    \caption{This figure needs to be inside figure 1}.
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This is figure 1, which is a pgfplots graphics.
[image: This is figure 1]

This is figure 2, which is a pgfplots graphics.
[image: This is figure 2]

This is figure 3, which is a jpg image.

[image: This is figure 3]

This is combined figure 1 and figure 2. Figure 2 is placed inside figure 1 in the upper left corner. I would like this figure to be a vector graphics
[image: This is combined figure 1 and figure 2]

This is combined figure 1 and figure 3. Figure 3 is placed inside figure 1 in the upper left corner. I would like figure 1 to be still a vector graphics.
[image: This is combined figure 1 and figure 3]

I would be thankful if someone could help me how I can insert other vector graphics as well as raster graphics in Asymptote and pgfplots.

Comment: Both Yes but insert where in the axis?

Comment: @percusse: thanks for your comment. Both in and outside the axis.

Comment: @Ahm: At the moment, your question is really to vague to be answered in a meaningful way. Could you please edit it to include more information on what exactly you're trying to achieve, ideally including a mockup of what you want the final result to look like?

Comment: @Jake: I made some modifications in the question for better clarification and illustrated a MWE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the `pgfplots` within `pgfplots` you could combine the two plots in the code, as seen in [How the plot in \groupplot could be moved horizontally and vertically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165736/how-the-plot-in-groupplot-could-be-moved-horizontally-and-vertically/165749#165749)

For the image, add the following inside the `axis` environment of figure 1:

```
\node [above right] at (rel axis cs:0.2,0.4) {\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{piv}};
```

The exact coordinates, which specify the location of lower left corner of the image, and the width should probably be modified. `rel axis cs` is a a coordinate system that has `(0,0)` in the lower left corner of the `axis`, and `(1,1)` in the upper right.

Note that if you have for example the `pgfplots` plot as a vectorised PDF, then including it this way will not rasterise it, so you can use this method for both.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            colormap={bw}{gray(0cm)=(0); gray(1cm)=(1)}]
        \addplot+[scatter,only marks,
             domain=0:8,samples=100]
            {exp(x)};

            \coordinate (otheraxis) at (rel axis cs:0.2,0.4);
        \end{axis}
        \begin{axis}[colormap/bluered,at={(otheraxis)},width=5cm]
        \addplot+[scatter,
             scatter src=x,samples=50]
            {sin(deg(x))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{This is the main figure.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            colormap={bw}{gray(0cm)=(0); gray(1cm)=(1)}]
        \addplot+[scatter,only marks,
             domain=0:8,samples=100]
            {exp(x)};

            \node [above right] at (rel axis cs:0.1,0.25) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{piv}};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{This is the main figure.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

As for Asymptote, you can use the `label` command to include external EPS graphics, as explained in [the manual](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/asymptote.pdf) (version 2.24, p. 19):

> The function `string graphic(string name, string options="")` returns a string that
>   can be used to include an encapsulated PostScript (EPS) file. Here, name is the name
>   of the file to include and options is a string containing a comma-separated list of optional
>   bounding box (`bb=llx lly urx ury`), width (`width=value`), height (`height=value`),
>   rotation (`angle=value`), scaling (`scale=factor`), clipping (`clip=bool`), and draft mode
>   (`draft=bool`) parameters. The `layer()` function can be used to force future objects to be
>   drawn on top of the included image:

```
label(graphic("file.eps","width=1cm"),(0,0),NE);
layer();
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems it is not possible to put a raster image into Asymptote. Would it be possible to put the image into the EPS file and then use the `label` function to insert it in Asymptote?

Comment: What do you mean by "putting the image into the EPS file"? What I would do is simply to convert this image to the EPS format and then include it via Asymptote in your picture.

Comment: what would you use to convert the image to an `EPS` format?

Comment: As for me I use the `convert` command-line tool of ImageMagick. In an Unix Terminal, it simply works like that: `convert file.png file.eps`. (here png is only an example of raster format.)

Comment: Converting to `eps` format is unnecessary if you use `settings.tex = pdflatex;`.

Comment: @CharlesStaats, it is `settings.tex = "pdflatex";`

Comment: @alfC: You are, of course, correct. Unfortunately I cannot edit my comment at theis point.

Answer (score 3):

Asymptote supports importing the external image directly, you can see its sample code in its GitHub source repo [orthocenter.asy](https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/blob/master/examples/orthocenter.asy), the png file is located here [piicon.png](https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/blob/master/examples/piicon.png) for a reference.

```
import geometry;
import math;

size(7cm,0);

if(!settings.xasy && settings.outformat != "svg") settings.tex="pdflatex";

real theta=degrees(asin(0.5/sqrt(7)));

pair B=(0,sqrt(7));
pair A=B+2sqrt(3)*dir(270-theta);
pair C=A+sqrt(21);
pair O=0;

pair Ap=extension(A,O,B,C);
pair Bp=extension(B,O,C,A);
pair Cp=extension(C,O,A,B);

perpendicular(Ap,NE,Ap--O,blue);
perpendicular(Bp,NE,Bp--C,blue);
perpendicular(Cp,NE,Cp--O,blue);

draw(A--B--C--cycle);

draw("1",A--O,-0.25*I*dir(A--O));
draw(O--Ap);
draw("$\sqrt{7}$",B--O,LeftSide);
draw(O--Bp);
draw("4",C--O);
draw(O--Cp);

dot("$O$",O,dir(B--Bp,Cp--C),red);
dot("$A$",A,dir(C--A,B--A),red);
dot("$B$",B,NW,red);
dot("$C$",C,dir(A--C,B--C),red);
dot("$A'$",Ap,dir(A--Ap),red);
dot("$B'$",Bp,dir(B--Bp),red);
dot("$C'$",Cp,dir(C--Cp),red);

label(graphic("piicon.png","width=2.5cm, bb=0 0 147 144"),Ap,5ENE);
```

Note the last statement of the code. Here is the result screen shot of the pdf.
[image: screen shot of the generated pdf]

Comment: Note that this works only with pdflatex, i.e. thanks to `settings.tex="pdflatex"` at the top.