How can I insert pictures into a graph using asymptote?
How can I insert pictures into a graph using asymptote? Below is an example picture.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hello.  The Asymptote "label" command can be used to insert graphics.  See the Asymptote answer at the following link.  Your graphics will need to be either EPS or PDF files as described in the comments at the link.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167355/70641

This question is similar to: Inserting graphics into asymptote or pgfplots. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
